# Create new Elasticsearch index from query?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

SQL has the "INSERT INTO ... SELECT" statement to fill a table with data from a query. Does anything like this exist for Elasticsearch?

This would prevent me from mass deleting data from an existing index using a query - which is something the official Elasticsearch 2.1 guide warns against:

> Don’t use delete-by-query to clean out all or most documents in an index. Rather create a new index and perhaps reindex the documents you want to keep.

(Source: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/plugins-delete-by-query.html).

Answer (score 4):

You can use the excellent utility from taskrabbit called [`elasticdump`](https://github.com/taskrabbit/elasticsearch-dump).

There are [many options](https://github.com/taskrabbit/elasticsearch-dump#options) to customize the import process. In your case, I would use the `searchBody` option and go with something like this:

```
elasticdump \
  --input=http://HOST:9200/source_index \
  --output=http://HOST:9200/target_index \
  --bulk=true \
  --searchBody='{"query": { "match_all": {} } }'
```

You can customize the query and only the matched documents from the `source_index` will be copied over to the `target_index`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the create index API:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-create-index.html

```
PUT /test
{
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "field1": { "type": "text" }
    }
  }
}
```